# The "Bibles" of American English Phonetics

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

Daniel Jones' *Outline of English Phonetics* and Alfred C. Gimson's *Introduction to the Pronunciation of English* are considered the "Bibles" of British English phonetics. 
Are there equivalent works in the American English tradition?

Comment: Kenyon and Knott's _Pronouncing Dictionary of American English_ for American phonemics and J.C. Catford's _A Practical Introduction to Phonetics_ for phonetics in general. For the differences, see David Crystal's _Cambridge Encylopedia of the English Language._ For the **details**, the [_Phonological Atlas of North America_](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/phono_atlas/home.html).

Comment: @JohnLawler: I think that you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: There's the information. I'm not getting paid for this, you know.

Comment: JL posts answers only when they don't fit in the 600 chr. comment box. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Bible-sized book on American English phonetics, check out: *[Atlas of North American English: Phonetics, Phonology and Sound Change](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3110167468)*

For the most popular book on the subject (ranked by the US amazon.com book website), check out: *[A Pronouncing Dictionary of American English](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0877790477)*